# How do I vertically align a drop down list?

Tags: html, css

How do I vertically center the text and the drop down list so that they are level?

```
<p>
<span>Hello World</span><select><option>Hello</option></select>
</p>

span {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/foaLrcn9/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the [`vertical-align` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) to `middle` for both of the elements:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/dw8b1c8u/)

```
span, select {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
span {
  font-size: 50px;
}
span,
select {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span>Hello World</span><select><option>Hello</option></select>
```

Comment: It may be useful to the OP to read about how Vertical Align actually works https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ and http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/

Comment: It still not quite doing it. Check out the drop downs at the bottom of the page.... http://bangface.com/merch

Comment: ...on Chrome browser.

Comment: @IanWarburton I just checked in Chrome and it seems fine. Which dropdown were you referring to? Or did you fix it?

Comment: @JoshCrozier Its passable. But the tops of the all the drop downs at the bottom of the page seem to be aligned with the tops of the labels. In IE it seems like a better vertical centering.